# SQL where on 2 values at the same column on left join

Tags: sql, database

I need a help:

I have a table called **phonograms**, **phonogram_instruments** and **filters**:

at the phonograms table, I have many data to fetch on my app. One phonogram has many phonogram_instruments and each phonogram_instrument belongs to a filter.

I need to fetch all phonograms that has phonogram_instrument.filter_id = 25 AND  phonogram_instrument.filter_id = 30

I have one query that works fine with one value:

```
SELECT * FROM "phonograms" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "phonogram_instruments" "phonogram_instruments_phonograms" 
   ON "phonogram_instruments_phonograms"."phonogram_id" = "phonograms"."id" 
WHERE 
   (phonogram_instruments_phonograms.filter_id = 29)
```

but if I put another value, it doesn't:

```
 SELECT * FROM "phonograms" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "phonogram_instruments" "phonogram_instruments_phonograms"
   ON "phonogram_instruments_phonograms"."phonogram_id" = "phonograms"."id" 
WHERE 
   (phonogram_instruments_phonograms.filter_id = 29)
   AND (phonogram_instruments_phonograms.filter_id = 25)
```

Could you help me? :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way a single filter_id row could have a value of 29 and 25 at the same time

So, you should use OR instead of AND

```
SELECT * FROM "phonograms" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "phonogram_instruments" "phonogram_instruments_phonograms" 
ON "phonogram_instruments_phonograms"."phonogram_id" = "phonograms"."id" 
WHERE 
 phonogram_instruments_phonograms.filter_id = 29
 OR phonogram_instruments_phonograms.filter_id = 25
```

And if your where statement contains more filters, put your filter_id filter statement between two brackets

```
SELECT * FROM "phonograms" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "phonogram_instruments" "phonogram_instruments_phonograms" 
ON "phonogram_instruments_phonograms"."phonogram_id" = "phonograms"."id" 
WHERE 
 (
   phonogram_instruments_phonograms.filter_id = 29
   OR phonogram_instruments_phonograms.filter_id = 25
 )
 AND ... other filters
```

Comment: each phonogram has many instruments and each instrument belongs to a filter. In my case, I have one phonogram with two instruments (the first one belongs to a filter with id 29 and another belongs to a filter with id 25) and I would like to fetch this unique phonogram.

Comment: @DiegoPolidoSantana, would you please add a sample data, and your expected data fro your select statement so that I can have a better understanding of your case ?

Comment: Then you have to add in the filter instead of `(phonogram_instruments_phonograms.filter_id = 29)` the Phonogram_id = 1 as follows `(phonogram_instruments_phonograms.phonogram_Id = 1)` this will get you the items that is related to this Id from the other table, which are the items with filter_id = 25 and 29

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to use the INTERSECT compound operator like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "phonograms" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "phonogram_instruments" "phonogram_instruments_phonograms" 
   ON "phonogram_instruments_phonograms"."phonogram_id" = "phonograms"."id" 
WHERE 
   phonogram_instruments_phonograms.filter_id = 29
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM "phonograms" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "phonogram_instruments" "phonogram_instruments_phonograms" 
   ON "phonogram_instruments_phonograms"."phonogram_id" = "phonograms"."id" 
WHERE 
   phonogram_instruments_phonograms.filter_id = 25
```

It's not particularly pretty and doesn't scale well if you need to intersect an arbitrary number of filter_ids (e.g. find all phonograms where phonogram_instrument.filter_id is 29, 25, and 37). In that case I might suggest an interesting alternative (which incidentally also works for just two values as well):

```
SELECT * FROM "phonograms", count(phonograms.id) as 'num_ids'
LEFT OUTER JOIN "phonogram_instruments" "phonogram_instruments_phonograms" 
   ON "phonogram_instruments_phonograms"."phonogram_id" = "phonograms"."id" 
WHERE 
   phonogram_instruments_phonograms.filter_id IN (29, 25)
GROUP BY
   phonograms.id
HAVING
   num_ids = 2
```

If you have more than 2 filter_ids, expand the parenthesized list in the WHERE clause and change the numeric value in the HAVING clause accordingly.